Issue with Super+N Shortcut in Ubuntu 24.04 When Accessing Google Drive
n the Dock, I have the following applications: Firefox, Chrome, and Files. Using the Super+number shortcut, it’s possible to open or switch between them: Super+1, Super+2, and Super+3 open Firefox, Chrome, and Files, respectively.
If Files (Super+3 in my case) is showing any folder, the shortcut works. Even if there are multiple windows, such as one showing the Images folder and another showing the Videos folder, the shortcut works. However, if the Files application is showing the Google Drive folder, pressing the shortcut opens a new Files window instead of switching to the already open one.
Another thing, when Driver folder is opened another app like fig.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZlqX52K2FQAxbS2GvgUQLzUfF0jr5ef/view?usp=sharing
I have used several versions of Ubuntu and have never encountered this anomalous behavior until using Ubuntu 24.04.
Is it possible to fix this?
EDIT:
I've following the instructions from @vanadium and print screen is
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AjELdKL9JApiclUJoeMZ5QZMDCVG4qWp/view?usp=drive_link
Left and below is from 1st Super+3 and navegate to Driver folder.
Right and below is from 2ns Super+3.
As can you see open new window.
I hope this helps! If you need any further assistance, feel free to ask.

You may want to file a bug report. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

ok, I never did and I hope u continuing help me, @David. In https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs, there's guide line to use ubuntu-bug buggy-package-name. Wich is pachage-name to Files?

Nautilus is the name of the app.

Can you do the following: 1) Close all programs 2) 2) Open a Files window showing the Google Drive folder. 3) Hit Super+3 and verify that a new Files window is opened 4) Now hit Alt+F2, then type 'lg' then Return. 5) In the window that appears, click the Windows button to show all windows. Take a screenshot and copy the information about the two windows here in your question. Add the info to your question: use "edit". Do not add extra information about the problem in a comment.

Sorry for the late. I hope that now is better to understand my problem
